# Value Range issue in time Date and time fields jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using jQuery Validate i'm using the following:

```
dateDay: {
    required: true,
    range: [1, 31]
},
dateMonth: {
    required: true,
    range: [1, 12]
},
dateYear: {
    required: true,
    range: [<?=date('Y')?>, <? $dateplus = date('Y', strtotime(' +2 years')); echo $dateplus;?>]
},
time1: {
    required: true,
    range: [0, 23]
},
time2: {
    required: true,
    range: [0, 59]
},
time3: {
    required: true,
    range: [0, 23]
},
time4: {
    required: true,
    range: [0, 59]
}
```

However when entering the following

```
dd / mm / yyyy
31 / 12 / 2016

15:30 - 16:00
```

It results in errors on those fields. Doing some more investigating it seems that all of the fields seem to throw up an error after going over the value of 12 and the minute fields (time2,time4) start working again at number 32. This makes me think that somewhere along the validation the numbers from dateDay and dateMonth are mixing up the rest of the script?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who comes across this and finds themselves frustrated for hours... DO NOT ADD A "date" CLASS TO YOUR DATE INPUTS!!!

If any of your date fields have a **'date'** class, it seemingly adds extra validation to these fields.

Comment: Yes, `date` is a validation rule and most validation rules for this plugin can be added to a field using a class name.